# Problems with within and random models in plm package

Tags: r, regression, plm

I am working with plm package and I have problem with random and within models, which are giving errors which says "empty model". However, the model is not empty. In the source code for plm.fit, where the error originates it says something like (writing from the top of my head...)

```
X <- model.matrix(formula,data, lhs=1,...)
if (ncol(X) == 0) stop("empty model")
```

however if I try to replicate this behaviour with the commands I am inputing into the original function, it gives ncol(X) is 17 or something like that.

My code is (data deleted...):

```
library(sampleSelection)
library(foreign)
library(censReg)
library(plm)
library(micEcon)
library(ggplot2)

data <- read.dta('kpfull1.dta')
summary(data)
attach(data)

data$profit_share <- p91/tnsvp
data$debt_assets <- d91/naba
data$naba3 <- naba^3
data$difprofit <- p91-p90
data$agri <- (mind==1)*1
data$hi <- (mind==2)*1
data$li <- (mind==3)*1
data$constr <- (mind==4)*1
data$trans <- (mind==5)*1
data$trade <- (mind==6)*1
data$rd <- (mind==7)*1
data$ser <- (mind==8)*1
data$fin <- (mind==9)*1
data$for1 <- data[,7]
detach(data)
data1 <- data
panel <- pdata.frame(data, c("num","rnd"))

testovaci <- plm(tb ~ profit_share  + debt_assets + naba + naba3 + for1 + dom + difprofit + agri + hi + li + constr + trans + trade + rd + ser + fin, data = panel, model = "within")
summary(testovaci)

model.matrix(tb ~ profit_share  + debt_assets + naba + naba3 + for1 + dom + difprofit + agri + hi + li + constr + trans + trade + rd + ser + fin, data)

model.matrix(tb ~ profit_share  + debt_assets + naba + naba3 + for1 + dom + difprofit + agri + hi + li + constr + trans + trade + rd + ser + fin, panel)
```

Thanks,
Tomáš Křehlík.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example -- one that includes a dataset and doesn't load all of those extraneous packages at the start?

Comment: No, because the bugs might be related to the packages masking function names, etc. You can easily comment all except foreign and plm. I added the data.

Answer (score 4):

Answered in R-help by Giovanni Millo:

> Dear Tomas, dear list,
>
> a follow-up, as in the meantime I got the data by private
>   communication. The problem, as I suspected, is hidden in some lack of
>   time variability in the data. In fact, OLS works fine:
>
> % `fm` is the formula, `data` is the dataset, `panel` is the dataset transformed as a `pdata.frame`
>
> `summary(lm(fm, data))`
>
> % (output ok, omitted)
>
> as does plm "pooling"
>
> `summary(plm(fm, panel, model="pooling"))`
>
> Oneway (individual) effect
>   Pooling Model
>
> % (output ok, omitted)
>
> but FE fails:
>
> `summary(plm(fm, panel, model="within"))`
>
> `Errore in plm.fit(formula,`
>   `data, model, effect, random.method, inst.method) :  empty model`
>
> as do the various RE methods
>
> `summary(plm(fm, panel, model="random"))`
>
> `Errore in plm.fit(formula,`
>   `data, model = "within", effect = effect) :  empty model`
>
> ...and if you look at the error message, it is clear that it is the
>   within/FE part that has problems (RE methods are based on FE for
>   estimating the error components). In fact, trying to panel-difference
>   any right-hand side variable results in all zeros (NaNs are for
>   variance shares, which are 0/0), e.g. the first one:
>
> `summary(diff(panel$profit_share))`
>
> `total sum of squares : 0  id time`
>   `NaN  NaN`
>
> but it is really the same for each. So the (within transformed) model
>   is actually empty, as the original error message says. Now I don't
>   have time to look deeply into the data, but the rhs variables all look
>   time-constant to me...
>
> The takeaway for panel guys on the list, therefore, is: main cause for
>   data-induced error is bad indices, second one is bad data variability;
>   first step to diagnose it is running `lm()` and then `plm(...,
>   model="pooling")`. `lm()` fails=> bad data, bad formula; `plm(...,
>   "pooling")` fails=> something basically wrong with indices; other panel
>   methods fail=> most likely data variability problems.
>
> Best, Giovanni
>
> PS I tried to circumvent the issue by ML estimation of an RE model but
>   no way, I got a singular matrix error: so the data really are
>   ill-conditioned
>
> `library(nlme) remod<-lme(tb ~ profit_share  + debt_assets + naba +
>   naba3 + for1 + dom + difprofit + agri + hi + li + constr + trans +
>   trade + rd + ser + fin, random=~1|num, data=data) Errore in
>   solve.default(estimates[dimE[1] - (p:1), dimE[2] - (p:1), drop =
>   FALSE]) :  il sistema è numericamente singolare: valore di condizione
>   di reciprocità = 3.93401e-25`