# plm fixed effects empty model in R

Tags: r, indexing, plm

I'm attempting to do a fixed effects regression in R using plm.

When I run a linear model, everything is fine.

`summary(lm(influence ~ geo_delta, data = mydata))`

When I run a pooling model, everything is fine.

`summary(plm(influence ~ geo_delta, data = mydata, model = 'pooling'))`

However, when I run a fixed effects model like so:

`summary(plm(influence ~ geo_delta, data = mydata, index = "email", model = "within"))`

I get the following error:

`Error in plm.fit(formula, data, model, effect, random.method, random.models,  : 
  empty model`

My intuition (based on a previous thread: [Problems with within and random models in plm package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404141/problems-with-within-and-random-models-in-plm-package)) is that there is something wrong with my indices. However, I'm not sure how to diagnose this.

Here is a screenshot of the data as it looks when I run `mydata`

[image: a screenshot of my data with redacted email addresses]

There appears to be an alignment issue on the left but I'm not sure if that's causing the problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you add the output of `table(mydata$email)`? I suspect you do not have a panel data set here and, thus, the FE model is not appropriate. Which variable shall serve as the time dimension? You do not specify one, so `plm` tries to derive it from the individual dimension.

Comment: So, in principle, `mydata$email` should have 2 records for each email address. So, I want FE within email. However, I see your point. If there are zero complete records, then there won't be a panel. I'll check the data quickly to see.

Comment: If you do not supply a second (=time) `index`, the data should be 'stacked' (see `?pdata.frame`). They are not as I can see from your screenshot. Suggestion is to convert your data to a `pdata.frame` first and lock at the index generated with `index(your_pdata.frame)` to check